# How to ADD label inside infinite button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect, cgrectmake

**This is my code:**

```
-(void)scrollView
{
    NSInteger buttonCount = 0;
    NSInteger buttonSize = 0;
    int divisible= 0;
    buttonCount=[[arrFullSubCategory valueForKey:@"name"]count];
    if(buttonCount==2)
    {
        divisible = 2;
        buttonSize=self.view.frame.size.width/divisible;
    }
    else
    {
        divisible = 3;
        buttonSize=self.view.frame.size.width/divisible;
    }

    [viewBtnScroll addSubview:self.scrollViewBtn];
    for(int i=0;i<buttonCount;i++)
    {
        self.scrollViewBtn.scrollsToTop=YES;
        self.scrollViewBtn.directionalLockEnabled=YES;
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
        UIButton *btn;
        btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonSize*i,0,buttonSize,self.scrollViewBtn.frame.size.height)];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrFullSubCategory objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        btn.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        NSInteger tag=[[[arrFullSubCategory valueForKey:@"category"] objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn setTag:tag];


 highLight=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonSize*i,10,btn.frame.size.width,20)];
        highLight.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        highLight.hidden=YES;
        [btn addSubview:highLight];
         [self.scrollViewBtn addSubview:btn];
        length = [[arrFullSubCategory valueForKey:@"name"] count];

    }

    self.scrollViewBtn.contentSize=CGSizeMake(buttonSize*buttonCount, self.scrollViewBtn.frame.size.height);
}
```

1.That button depend up on the coming json values.

2.That button size is calculated for the screen size.

3.i have created label as globally for some reason,and added that to subview of button ,initially it is hide ,when the button pressed that particular button label hidden=NO;

4.everything i have done perfectly,but my problem is How to give x.origin for the particular label?

5.From my code the label present only at end of the button not for all.

6.If i set x.origin as 0 then its present only at the initial button[first button].

7.That button present in scrollview .....

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution for this would be

1. create new `UIView` (lets name it `MyView`) of the size you want.
2. create `UILabel` of size you want and x and y with respect to `MyView`
   and add it to `MyView`
3. Add `MyView` to your `UIScrollView`.
4. Then create a `UIButton` of the same dimensions as `MyView` and add it to you same `UIScrollView`

Important here is you add button to your `UIScrollView` and not `MyView`

and you are good to go .. hope this helps...

**======= EDITS ======== Use the code as you need**

```
    float width = GridScrollView.frame.size.width;
    int i,k=0;

    for ( i= 0; i < imageArray.count; i+=4) {

        for (int j =0; j<4; j++) {


            if (i+j <nameArray.count) {



                NSLog(@"i = %d    j = %d    k = %d",i,j,k);
                UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner2 = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((width/4)*j ,(width/4)*k , width/4, width/4)];

                [spinner2 startAnimating];
                [GridScrollView addSubview:spinner2];
                UIView *gridBox = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((width/4)*j ,(width/4)*k , width/4, width/4)];
                //                            gridBox.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

                [GridScrollView addSubview:gridBox];



                UIView *labelBack = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((width/4)*j ,(width/4)*k , width/4, width/16)];
                labelBack.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
                labelBack.alpha=0.5;

                [GridScrollView addSubview:labelBack];


                UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((width/4)*j ,(width/4)*k , width/4, width/16)];
                nameLabel.text=nameArray[i+j];
                nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                nameLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
                nameLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
                [GridScrollView addSubview:nameLabel];


                UIButton *gridButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((width/4)*j ,(width/4)*k , width/4, width/4)];
                [gridButton addTarget:self action:@selector(gridButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                gridButton.tag=i+j;
                [GridScrollView addSubview:gridButton];



            }

        } k++;

    }
    [GridScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, (width/4)*(i/4))];

    [self.view addSubview:GridScrollView];
```

Comment: saiyyad no the n number of button is scrollable so if i add the label as subView to button then it will be easy ....if i set the label in uiview it will be static non scrollable...

Comment: It will be... Put a loop from zero to array.count. and create a view everytime and add it to scrollview.  Wait Let me post the code for you. :)